# symfony 2 sending an object from a template to a controller

Tags: symfony

I need to send an object from a template to a controller. In this case I want to send the product object. Is it possible to send that object as argument in path ?

```
{% for product in products %} 
    <p>{{ product.name }} Price: {{ product.price}} <a href="{{ path('ShopMyShopBundle_addproduct')  }}">Add product</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{% for product in products %} 
    <p>{{ product.name }} Price: {{ product.price}} 
    <a href="{{ path('ShopMyShopBundle_addproduct', {id : product.id})  }}">Add product</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

But better way is using html form:

```
<form action="{{ path('ShopMyShopBundle_addproduct') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {# hidden fields #}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add product" />
</form>
```